# Where does IIS store site bindings?

Tags: iis-7.5

I have a large amount of sites running on *IIS 7.5* on *Windows Server 2008 R2* Standard, each with many bindings configured. I need to extract the bindings into a text file.

One method is to manually go through each binding for each site within IIS, but it is a painstaking task. It would be easier to access them via a text file. I was lead to believe that site and binding combinations were stored in this file: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`, but I only see a subset of the sites that are configured on the server, and not all of those have all the bindings. So my question is, where does IIS store all of the site bindings?

I'm hoping it's in the form of an accessible text file (e.g. a `.config` file). If it is in the form of an accessible text file, I only need read access for now, but it would be good to know if this file can be written to rather than needing to edit bindings via IIS, and if so, does the file require administrator level access.

Comment: I suspect all the entries are there, just that they are scattered throughout the file.

Comment: Just my cents, but fFound all relevant bindings at applicationHost.config

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that you have opened `applicationHost.conf` with a 32-bit editor (like notepad++).

If you do that it will open `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.conf` and not `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`.

Check this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/331187/directly-editing-iis-7-applicationhost-config-configuration-file) for more information.

If you open the file with a 64-bit editor (like Windows notepad), you will see all your websites.